# How "Subscription Status Url" works for apple In-app purchases (Auto renewable)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

Does anybody work on "**Subscription Status Url**" and how it works for Auto Renewable In-app purchases in the sandbox mode

When i am trying to achive it, i am able to subscribe my product from App but while checking subscription status in the backend (server) we are not getting any "statusUpdateNotifications" from Apple Server. We have tested our URL and it is as per Apple security norms.

We went through below link but didn't get much information

[Working with Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html)

Comment: I am also experiencing this same issue.

Comment: I have also verified that my service is SSL/TLSv1.2 to be certain I am hosting my service correctly. I also set it up to where when the endpoint is hit I would be emailed the body of the request. I have been waiting for 24+ hours now and still haven't gotten any emails. I know the endpoint works correctly via testing with postman. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: check if this question solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120177/how-to-check-in-app-purchase-auto-renewable-subscription-is-valid?rq=1

Comment: I'm also find answer for this issue !